# Как определить что год високосный?

Tags: python

Код не проходит тесты, но я не могу найти ошибку:

```
year = int(input())
if year != 0:
    if year % 400 == 0:
        print('YES')
    elif year % 4 == 0:
        if year % 100 != 0:
            print('YES')
    else:
        print('NO')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Задание:

[image: Задание]

Comment: введите 1900 - поймете ошибку ;)

Comment: Спасибо. А скажите как это работает?

Comment: Не понял вопроса - вы спрашиваете как работает ваш код или как написать правильно?

Comment: Я просто не понял почему такая ошибка получается, но сейчас вроде как разобрался) пойду исправлять

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При вводе числа, кратного 100, ваш код ничего не напечатает.

Попробуйте так:

```
def is_leap(year):
    if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0:
        return True
    if year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    return False

print("YES" if is_leap(int(input())) else "NO")
```

PS если вас не обманули составители задачи и тестов (`дано натуральное число`), то нет смысла проверять `if year != 0`

---

**UPD:** Любителям однострочников посвящается ;)

```
def is_leap(year):
    return (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or year % 400 == 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Зачем придумывать, когда уже есть готовое:

```
import calendar

year = int(input("Year: "))
if calendar.isleap(year):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

*Понимаю-понимаю, что для учёбы :)*